# Authorize facebook app to post to page wall, but not to users walls

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app which can post to the wall of a page by using the administrators 'publish_stream" permission. However I don't want to have the ability to post all over a user's wall, only the pages they control.

Since this is being done automatically I will need a permanent token (offline_access) and obviously the publish_stream permission. But I'm unsure how to request this.

I have seen some applications, like the notes app in pages which have a setting for `allow this app to post on wall`. This would be easier, but otherwise does anyone know how I can request publish_stream permission for a page via the graph api?

For example, this is the request I use to get the user authorization code before requesting a token. I can't find an equivalent to request authorization for a *page* though.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get permission to access only a page's wall / news feed without access to the user's also.  If you're worried about "accidentally" posting to the user's wall and not to the page, you can make sure you use the access_token provided in the `/me/accounts` endpoint for your user.

So, your choices are pretty limited here if you want to use the `offline_access` permission to post to a pages wall.  Limited, as in, you need to have `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions.